# Pandas: do not rename columns when reading csv

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to avoid automatic naming of columns with empty names (resulting for instance in “Unnamed: 13”) when reading data with pandas.read_csv?

- Example

Name row in csv file:

```
name_1;name_2;;name_4
```

Names generated by read_csv:

```
["name_1", "name_2", "Unnamed: 3", "name_4"]
```

Desired names:

```
["name_1", "name_2", "", "name_4"]
```

Comment: you could provide your own names

Comment: @PaulH: I want to use the names as they are, simply keeping an empty string when the name is empty in the csv.

Comment: So you're going to have a bunch of blank column names? What does this accomplish? You can just go through and rename the columns that have "Unnamed" and replace with "".

Answer (score 0):

You can rename columns after loading the CSV:

```
def rename(col):
    if col.startswith("Unnamed: "):
        return ""
    else:
        return col

data.columns = [rename(col) for col in data.columns]
```

I would not recommend it, and you should make sure there are no actual columns starting with "Unnamed: ", but otherwise this should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

After you read it, you could do something like

`df.columns = [x if not x.startswith('Unnamed') else i for i,x in enumerate(df.columns)]`

That will replace the unnamed columns with an integer corresponding to that columns place. If you really want it to just be blank, you could do

`df.columns = [x if not x.startswith('Unnamed') else "" for x in df.columns]`